# How to plot a stepline at crossings?

Tags: pine-script, trendline

I want to plot a simple trend line (I thought it was simple). when the daily price moves from above the previous quarter high and then crosses below the previous quarter low, I want to plot the previous quarter high as a horizontal line, until the moment that the daily price crosses up above the previous quarter high, then I want to plot the previous quarter low as a horizontal line and so on. I want to plot this as a stepline, but all I get are points at the crossings.

[example of line to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlNAK.jpg)

```
//@version=3 
//By Juros
study(title="previous Quarter high & low", shorttitle="Prev Quar H-L", overlay=true,     precision=8)
PQH = input(true, title="Show Previous Quarter High & Low?")


//Quarterly
prevQuarterHigh = security(tickerid, '3M', high[1], lookahead=true)
prevQuarterLow = security(tickerid, '3M', low[1], lookahead=true)


plot(PQH and prevQuarterHigh ? prevQuarterHigh : na, title="Prev Quarter High", style=stepline, linewidth=1, color=blue,transp=0)
plot(PQH and prevQuarterLow ? prevQuarterLow : na, title="Prev Quarter Low", style=stepline,    linewidth=1, color=blue,transp=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is relatively simple to do, but your code can't guess what you are trying to do; you need the explicit logic implemented in your code.

`and prevQuarterHigh` will always be true because `prevQuarterHigh` is always different than zero, so the plot statements plotted as long as `PQH` was also true.

```
//@version=3 
//By Juros
study(title="previous Quarter high & low", shorttitle="Prev Quar H-L", overlay=true,     precision=8)
PQH = input(true, title="Show Previous Quarter High & Low?")

//Quarterly
prevQuarterHigh = security(tickerid, '3M', high[1], lookahead=true)
prevQuarterLow = security(tickerid, '3M', low[1], lookahead=true)

upTrend = false
upTrend := (not upTrend[1] and crossover(close, prevQuarterHigh)) or (upTrend[1] and not crossunder(close, prevQuarterLow))

plot(PQH and not upTrend ? prevQuarterHigh : na, title="Prev Quarter High", style=linebr, linewidth=1, color=blue,transp=0)
plot(PQH and upTrend ? prevQuarterLow : na, title="Prev Quarter Low", style=linebr, linewidth=1, color=blue,transp=0)
```

[image]

Comment: TNX, very elegant solution.